# Sample Standard Deviation in a DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, dataframe, standard-deviation

The following is the snippet of the data I have in my DataFrame.

```
Date                Energy  F1  F2  F3      F4      F5      F6  F7      F8
2013-01-01 00:00:00 0.181   7.0 5.0 0.87    1000.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    3.0
2013-01-01 00:30:00 0.248   7.0 5.0 0.87    1000.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    3.0
2013-01-01 01:00:00 0.206   7.0 5.0 0.87    1000.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    3.0
2013-01-01 01:30:00 0.171   7.0 5.0 0.87    1000.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    3.0
2013-01-01 02:00:00 0.068   7.0 5.0 0.87    1000.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    3.0
2013-01-01 02:30:00 0.083   7.0 5.0 0.87    1000.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    3.0
2013-01-01 03:00:00 0.083   7.0 5.0 0.87    1000.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    3.0
2013-01-01 03:30:00 0.072   7.0 5.0 0.87    1000.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    3.0
2013-01-01 04:00:00 0.06    7.0 5.0 0.87    1000.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    3.0
2013-01-01 04:30:00 0.061   7.0 5.0 0.87    1000.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    3.0
2013-01-01 05:00:00 0.06    7.0 5.0 0.87    1001.0  10.0    4.0 16.7    4.0
2013-01-01 05:30:00 0.068   6.0 3.0 0.81    1002.0  10.0    4.0 22.2    2.0
2013-01-01 06:00:00 0.076   6.0 3.0 0.81    1002.0  10.0    4.0 22.2    2.0
2013-01-01 06:30:00 0.044   5.0 2.0 0.81    1002.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    1.0
2013-01-01 07:00:00 0.063   5.0 2.0 0.81    1003.0  10.0    4.0 13.0    1.0
2013-01-01 07:30:00 0.063   5.0 2.0 0.81    1003.0  10.0    4.0 16.7    1.0
```

I would like to compute the Sample Standard Deviation for the Energy Column in such a way that every 4 values (window of 4 values) have one sample std.

I tried using the pd.rolling().std()

```
df['Smaple Std'] = df['Energy'].rolling(4).std()
```

but what this does is basically move from one row to the next, and groups the next 4 rows as a window. Give me a new Sample Std value for each row.

What I'm looking for is one Sample Std value for each 4 rows, and the window moves to the next 4 rows. This window changes in size [4, 8, 6, 6], this repeats

I was wondering if I could use groupby() but since my data, df is very large it becomes computationally expensive.

Any easy pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Instead of `.rolling()`, use `.resample()`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. But I forgot to mention that the window size will change. I have edited my question.

Comment: I do not see any edits.

Comment: I just made, the windows change from [4, 8, 6, 6] then again start from [4, 8, 6, 6] and so on...

Comment: I do not think this is easily (or efficiently) doable.

Comment: Thank you @DyZ for your feedback. Is there a suggestion you have? that could work but as you say might not be efficient.

Comment: If you know which rows belong to which window, you can group enumerate them and then call `groupby`. It is not clear from your question, as written, how and when the window changes.

Comment: It starts with 4, and moves to 8, 6, 6, and again resets to 4... and so on as it moves down the datetime index. So this window change is consistent.